# How to keymap using Xmodmap in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, xmodmap

I am having a problem key mapping my left <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key to right click. When I run the command, it does nothing.

I am trying to key map my left <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key to right click because my right click suddenly stopped working. While waiting for a new mouse, I want to key map my keyboard keys to the mouse for temporary uses.

Here is the command I entered to terminal

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = Pointer_Button3"
```

I am using Linux Mint as my operating system.

Comment: see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/336674/emulating-mouse-click-with-a-keyboard)

Comment: @Andra i forgot to run "xkbset" that why it not working thank you.